# ld: library not found for -lpthread

Tags: c++, c, macos, linker

I am trying to compile a program on Mac 10.9.1 but am facing a problem. On running gcc command with -lpthread flag to create a dylib , the linking fails with the following error.

```
ld : library not found for -lpthread.
```

libpthread.dylib is located in /usr/lib/

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: Generally, the GCC -lX flag will attempt to link with the shared library named "libX". In your case you're trying to link "libpthread" which can not be found. Specify the location with this flag: "-L/folder/containing/libpthread".

Comment: Please try `gcc -pthread ...` (without 'l'), see if it works.

Comment: I have tried the solutions mentioned in the replies, but none seems to completely solve the problem. Note : the compiler in use is g++ (ver 4.2.1)

On using -pthread instead of -lpthread, the error for lpthread went away , but now i am facing another linking error

ld: library not found for libstdc++

Using -L/usr/lib during linking means that i need to change a lot of files on my project.

I want to say that i was not facing this issue on my 10.8.6 system. This problem is there only with a new installation of 10.9.1.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to specify the directory that contains the `libpthread.dylib` file, which on most Macs is `/usr/lib`. Do this using the `-L` argument to `ld`, as in `ld -L/usr/lib -lpthread`.

Edit: `gcc` also accepts the `-L` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-lpthread` is technically not the right way to do it. You get better, more portable results by using `-pthread` on the GCC command line. Use it for the compile and the link. It will set important preprocessor definitions *and* link the necessary libraries.